# Is it possible to have two concurrent console connections in windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

In Windows, if you logon from the actual station (machine's keyboard and mouse), your connection is showed as "console" in Task Manager/Users. If you log on remotely your connection is showed as "TCP".

Is it possible to remotely connect to Windows remotely so that your connection appears as "console" without connecting to the user that is already logged on the machine? Two concurrent console connections, one of them remotely, is what I need.

I'm working in tech support. I have to manage 150+ windows machines located in different cities. The problem is that one of the applications that I have to support can be run only from "console". I need to support them without disturbing the user from his work with remote desktop software.

I tried on microsoft.com, google.com, stackoverflow and others but all I can find is how to allow concurrent connections on all windows versions but nothing that can help me. All machines are connected thru VPN. I tried to log on the support user, close the rdp connection and connect thru remote software, no good. I've tried to run the application with the "runas" command, but still no good.

I'm not afraid of any programing language. I need a starting point, different from the ones tried by me

Comment: what is the need for this?

Comment: I'm working in tech support. I have to manage 150+ windows machines located in different cities. The problem is that one of the applications that I have to support can be run only from "console". I need to support them without disturbing the user from his work with remote desktop software. All machines are connected thru VPN

Comment: I have never heard of that being possible. I'd look into other ways to administer that particular application.

Comment: Such as ... ? :)

Comment: PSExec might work since it runs locally on the remote machine

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run a process in the background of a client type machine, I would use PSExec (downloadable from Microsoft as part of the PSTools package) or WINRS, which is built into Windows already.  These will allow you to execute a program in the background without interacting with the user at all. The downside to these commands is that unless the program you're running has a built in command line interface, you will be unable to interact with it in any meaningful way, so make sure it can run entirely on its own before firing it off.  I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do in the background, but we use PSExec at our office to do things like remote patch installs and remote software loads.

Comment: I've tried psexec and all goes well when I'm deploying .bat files. The problem is that our company use an online portal that can be accessed only with use of certificates in IE. I've tried to open IE with runas, psexec and shellrunas remotely from my machine and from the same machine, using remote desktop logged in as a different user and the end user but the certificate won't work. I have to jump into the users session and correct the problems. This is not such a big deal as it takes me few minutes, but it would be nice not disturbing the user with my work